# Nutch 2.3.1 on cassandra couldn't start

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, nutch

I'm trying to run nutch 2.3.1 with cassandra. Followed steps on http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/Nutch2Cassandra . Finally, when I try to start nutch with command:

```
bin/crawl urls/ test http://localhost:8983/solr/ 2
```

I got the following exception:

```
GeneratorJob: starting
GeneratorJob: filtering: false
GeneratorJob: normalizing: false
GeneratorJob: topN: 50000
GeneratorJob: java.lang.RuntimeException: job failed: name=[test]generate: 1454483370-31180, jobid=job_local1380148534_0001
    at     org.apache.nutch.util.NutchJob.waitForCompletion(NutchJob.java:120)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.GeneratorJob.run(GeneratorJob.java:227)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.GeneratorJob.generate(GeneratorJob.java:256)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.GeneratorJob.run(GeneratorJob.java:322)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.GeneratorJob.main(GeneratorJob.java:330)

Error running:
  /home/user/apache-nutch-2.3.1/runtime/local/bin/nutch generate -D    mapred.reduce.tasks=2 -D mapred.child.java.opts=-Xmx1000m -D mapred.reduce.tasks.speculative.execution=false -D mapred.map.tasks.speculative.execution=false -D mapred.compress.map.output=true -topN 50000 -noNorm -noFilter -adddays 0 -    crawlId webmd -batchId 1454483370-31180
Failed with exit value 255.
```

When I check logs/hadoop.log, here's the error message:

```
2016-02-03 15:18:14,741 ERROR connection.HConnectionManager - Could not start connection pool for host localhost(127.0.0.1):9160
...
2016-02-03 15:18:15,185 ERROR store.CassandraStore - All host pools marked down. Retry burden pushed out to client.
me.prettyprint.hector.api.exceptions.HectorException: All host pools marked down. Retry burden pushed out to client.
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.HConnectionManager.getClientFromLBPolicy(HConnectionManager.java:390)
```

But my cassandra server is up:

```
runtime/local$ netstat -l |grep 9160
tcp        0      0 172.16.230.130:9160     *:*                     LISTEN
```

Anyone can help on this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The address of Cassandra is not `localhost`, it's `172.16.230.130`. That is the reason, Nutch cannot connect to the Cassandra store.

Hope this helps,

Le Quoc Do